# PYTHON: Filtering a dataset and truncating a date

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

I am fairly new to python, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have a dataset that I need to filter down to specific events.  For example, I have a column with dates and I need to know what dates are in the current month and have happened within the past week.  The column is called POS_START_DATE with dates formatted like 2019-01-27T00:00:00-0500. I need to truncate that date and compare it to the previous week.  No luck so far.

Here is my code so far:

```
## import data package
import datetime

## assign date variables
today = datetime.date.today()

six_day = datetime.timedelta(days = 6)

## Create week parameter
week = today + six_day

## Statement to extract recent job movements
if fields.POS_START_DATE < week and fields.POS_START_DATE > today:
      out1 += in1
```

Here is sample of the table:

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzXtm.png)

I am looking for the same table filtered down to only rows that happened within one week. The bottom of the sample table(not shown) will have dates in this month.  I'd like the final output to only show those rows, and any other rows in the current month of November.

Comment: Well, for starters having a value that is less than x - 6 and greater than x is impossible, so you might want to check the if statement. Also, what issue are you having with the code? Could you add the table and a tiny expected output please?

Comment: I should add the 6 and not subtract.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I have changed the calculation, however I am still not getting the correct results

Comment: Alright Im commuting now, but I think we have enough info now to help you, I'll get at it when I get home!

Comment: I appreciate your assistance.  As a new python user I'm still learning, and this website is a tremendous help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too sure to understand what is your expected output, but this will help you create an extra column which will be used as flag for those cases that fulfill with the condition you state in your `if-statement`:

```
import numpy as np
fields['flag_1'] = np.where(((fields['POS_START_DATE'] < week) & (fields['POS_START_DATE'] > today)),1,0)
```

This will generate an extra column in your dataframe with a 1 for the cases that meet the criteria you stated. Finally you can perform this calculation to get the total of cases that actually met the criteria:

```
total_cases = fields['flag_1'].sum()
```

#### Edit:

If you need to filter the data with only the cases that meet the criteria you can either use pandas filtering with the original `if-statement` (without creating the extra flag field) like this:

```
df_filtered = fields[(fields['POS_START_DATE'] < week) & (fields['POS_START_DATE'] > today)]
```

Or, if you created the flag, then much simpler:

```
df_filtered = fields[fields['flag'] == 1]
```

Both should work to generate a new dataframe, with only the cases that match your criteria.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help.  What's the best option to generate a dataset of all the flagged rows that meet my criteria?  I'm guessing create a loop that will cycle the whole dataset?

Comment: Edited in answer :) Sorry for forgetting about it last night!

Comment: I'm creating this code in data3sixty, so I am not sure Pandas are possible to import.  I will try the flagged version with the filtered option if that's the case.  No need for apologies, thank you for helping a noob like myself.

Comment: I assumed we were using panda's all along haha I hope the answer works well for you!

Comment: I just got confirmation from infogix that it can be imported, so your method should work.  I am currently coding it out, and I will keep you posted.  Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers, feel free to let me know if something else pops up along the way.